# R-Install and run multiple R versions on Mac

Tags: r, macos, version

I'm trying to install two different R versions ([R-3.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old/) and [R-3.2.1](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)) on a Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion).
I first installed R-3.0.0 and then as suggested [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-mac@r-project.org/msg00559.html), I ran the command:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget R-3.0.0.pkg
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

> No receipt for 'R-3.0.0.pkg' found at '/'.

Does anyone know where to find this receipt so that I can install R-3.2.1 and run [Rswitch](http://r.research.att.com/#other) correctly?

Answer (score 7):

**I recommend using [*rig*](https://github.com/r-lib/rig) (“The R Installation Manager”) instead of installing parallel versions of R manually.**

But if you want to perform the installation manually, you need to specify the *package name* with `pkgutil --forget`, not the installation package *filename*.

[*R installation and administration*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Multiple-versions) contains a summary of what’s necessary to parallel install multiple versions of R.

In particular, there are *multiple* packages associated with the R installation. Since these are subject to change I won’t list them here. Instead, you can find them yourself by running

```bash
pkgutil --pkgs | grep -i org.r-project
```

(The `-i` flag is important since some packages start with `org.r-project`, while others start with `org.R-`. The linked documentation currently fails to mention this!)

All of these need to be forgot. This is fairly straightforward; for instance, the following will work:

```bash
pkgutil --pkgs | grep -i org.r-project | xargs -I {} sudo pkgutil --forget {}
```

After that, you can manually install another version of R by runnings its pkg installer.

Answer (score 3):

[Though this question is quite old, google search still leads here]

With R.3.1.0 installed and attempting to run R.3.3.0 in parallel, I received the same message

```
pkgutil --forget org.r-project.R.mavericks.fw.pkg
No receipt for 'org.r-project.R.mavericks.fw.pkg' found at '/'.
```

Here onwards, I continued installation of R.3.3.0 and it all works like a dream. Previous packages of R.3.1.0 are functional and not affected.

Comment: Same here. For R 4.0.0 I ran (as stated in the install dialog) `pkgutil --forget org.R-project.R.fw.pkg` and got the same message. But it worked with RSwitch nonetheless, works flawlessly including my old library.

Answer (score 2):

Use RSwitch from bob rudis. It works on versions of MacOS beyond 10.14, and has additional features, like help and update checking

https://rud.is/rswitch/

Answer (score 0):

I use the `sudo pkgutil --forget R-3.0.0.pkg`, but I run that first, before installing the newer version of R. From your question, it sounds like you are running it after the install.

From the package installer: "Note: By default the installer upgrades previous Mavericks build of R if present. If you want to keep the previous version, use
pkgutil --forget org.r-project.R.mavericks.fw.pkg"

That order of operations works for me. Give it a try and then see if Rswitch works for you?